# Randomize Scale on Particle Properties

Tags: particles, transforms, random

I am completely new to Blender and want to build a cube as a particle system. My particle is an object collection of 2 objects (cube, cone). I use Volume as Emitter, no physics and a Lifetime of 2 frames. Moreover there is a randomization of rotation and random scale. The question is how is it possible to scale x,y,z separately at every particle wich is generated in the particle system. My goal is that every particle cube has a random x,y,z scale but scale even. The picture shows how the particels in the particle system should look but I have no Idea how to scale the axis uneven randomly.

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there's no option to control axes individually in the particles system. However, a similar result might be possible with geo nodes.